# Python - simple reading lines from a pipe

Tags: python, pipe, producer-consumer

I'm trying to read lines from a pipe and process them, but I'm doing something silly and I can't figure out what. The producer is going to keep producing lines indefinitely, like this:

producer.py

```
import time

while True:
    print 'Data'
    time.sleep(1)
```

The consumer just needs to check for lines periodically:

consumer.py

```
import sys, time
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        print 'Got data:', line
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this in the Windows shell as `python producer.py | python consumer.py`, it just sleeps forever (never seems to get data?) It seems that maybe the problem is that the producer never terminates, since if I send a finite amount of data then it works fine.

How can I get the data to be received and show up for the consumer? In the real application, the producer is a C++ program I have no control over.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some old versions of Windows simulated pipes through files (so they were prone to such problems), but that hasn't been a problem in 10+ years.  Try adding a

```
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

to the producer after the `print`, and also try to make the producer's stdout unbuffered (by using `python -u`).

Of course this doesn't help if you have no control over the producer -- if it buffers too much of its output you're still going to wait a long time.

Unfortunately - while there are many approaches to solve that problem on Unix-like operating systems, such as pyexpect, [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/), [exscript](http://code.google.com/p/exscript/), and [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/), I doubt any of them works on Windows; if that's indeed the case, I'd try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which puts enough of a Linux-like veneer on Windows as to often enable the use of Linux-like approaches on a Windows box.

Answer (score 7):

This is about I/O that is bufferized by default with Python. Pass `-u` option to the interpreter to disable this behavior:

```
python -u producer.py | python consumer.py
```

It fixes the problem for me.