# Using pipes to communicate data between two anonymous python scripts

Tags: python, windows, pipe

Consider this at the windows commandline.

```
scriptA.py | scriptB.py
```

I want to send a dictionary object from scriptA.py to scriptB.py by pickle:ing it and sending it over a pipe. But I don't know how to accomplish this.

I've read some posts about this subject here, but usually there's answers along these line:

```
Popen( "scriptA.py"´, ..., and so on )
```

But I don't actually know the name of "scriptA.py". I just want to get hold of the ready pipe object and send/receive the databuffer.

I've tried sys.stdout/stdout, but I get file-descriptor errors and basically haven't tried that track very far.

The process is simple:

scriptA.py:

- (1) Pickle/Serialize dictionary into stringbuffer
- (2) Send stringbuffer over pipe

scriptB.py

- (3) Receive stringbuffer from pipe
- (4) Unpickle/Deserialize stringbuffer into dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say this to a shell

```
scriptA.py | scriptB.py
```

The shell connects them with a pipe.  You do NOTHING and it works perfectly.

Everything that `scriptA.py` writes to sys.stdout goes to `scriptB.py`

Everything that `scriptB.py` reads from sys.stdin came from `scriptA.py`

They're already connected.

So, how do you pass a dictionary from stdout in A to stdin in B?

1. [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).  `scriptA.py` dumps the dictionary to stdout.  `scriptB.py` loads the dictionary from stdin.
2. [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).  `scriptA.py` dumps the dictionary to stdout.  `scriptB.py` loads the dictionary from stdin.

This is already built-in to Python and takes very, very little code.

In scriptA, `json.dump( {}, sys.stdout )` or `pickle.dump( {}, sys.stdout )`

In scriptB, `json.load( sys.stdin )` or `pickle.load( sys.stdin )`

Comment: EXCEPT if he's on Windows and Python is being invoked by "file association" (a.py | b.py) instead of directly referencing the Python executable (python a.py | python b.y) or e.g. (\python26\python a.py | \python26\python) -- like he said, you get dark mutterings about "invalid file descriptor"; it's long-standing bug in Windows cmd.exe. Concidentally another questioner raised this issue only a few minutes ago.

Comment: Sorry; forgot the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057638/bad-pipe-filedescriptor-when-reading-from-stdin-in-python

Comment: That was not someone else, it was me since I bumped into it when trying this solution. There's however an even older question about the file association problem which I redirected to instead.

Comment: I tried to put a `pickle.dump(['a string',],sys.stdout)` in striptA.py, and `pickle.load(sys.stdin)` in scriptB.py. But running `python scriptA.py | python scriptB.py` will result in an error from the pickle.load() line, as long as there is a print statement in scriptA.py. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The pipe just puts stdout of A to stdin of B.

A does:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.writelines(output)
```

B just does:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are piping something, you are (generally) feeding the standard output of one program into the standard input of another. I think you should keep trying this path.

If you're having trouble just being able to read the output of your first script with your second, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965210/python-simple-reading-lines-from-a-pipe).