# Bad pipe filedescriptor when reading from stdin in python

Tags: python, windows, pipe

**Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466801/python-piping-on-windows-why-does-this-not-work) question. Vote to close.**

Consider this at the windows commandline.

```
scriptA.py | scriptB.py
```

In scriptA.py:

```
sys.stdout.write( "hello" )
```

In scriptB.py:

```
print sys.stdin.read()
```

This generates the following error:

```
c:\> scriptA.py | scriptB.py
close failed: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\scriptB.py", line 20, in <module>
    print sys.stdin.read()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

The "close failed" message seems to come from execution of scriptA.py.

It doesn't matter if I use sys.stdin.read(), sys.stdin.read(1), sys.stdin.readlines() etc etc.

What's wrong?

**Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466801/python-piping-on-windows-why-does-this-not-work) question. Vote to close.**

Comment: I just tried it with python a.py | python b.py , which works fine. See Johan's answer for the reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that stdin/stdout redirect does not work when starting from a file association.
This is not specific to python, but a problem caused by win32 cmd.exe.

See: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2004-August/024920.html

Comment: Please consider editing your response so that it states that the problem is in Windows CMD.EXE, not in Python.

Comment: Not sure if this problem is really Windows specific, as I just encountered something similar on Linux - see my entry [Linux: Pipe into Python (ncurses) script, stdin and termios - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999114/linux-pipe-into-python-ncurses-script-stdin-and-termios)