# Linux: Pipe into Python (ncurses) script, stdin and termios

Tags: python, linux, pipe, ncurses, termios

Apparently this is almost a duplicate of "[Bad pipe filedescriptor when reading from stdin in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057638/bad-pipe-filedescriptor-when-reading-from-stdin-in-python)"; however, I believe this case is slightly more complicated (*and it is not Windows specific, as the conclusion of that thread was*).

I'm currently trying to experiment with a simple script in Python: I'd like to supply input to the script - either through command line arguments; or by 'pipe'-ing a string to this script - and have the script show this input string using a `curses` terminal interface.

The full script, here called `testcurses.py`, is given below. The problem is that whenever I try the actual piping, that seems to mess up stdin, and the `curses` window never shows. Here is a terminal output:

```
## CASE 1: THROUGH COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT (arg being stdin):
##
$ ./testcurses.py -
['-'] 1
stdout/stdin (obj): <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0xb77dc078> <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb77dc020>
stdout/stdin (fn): 1 0
env(TERM): xterm xterm
stdin_termios_attr [27906, 5, 1215, 35387, 15, 15, ['\x03', ... '\x00']]
stdout_termios_attr [27906, 5, 1215, 35387, 15, 15, ['\x03', ... '\x00']]
opening -
obj <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb77dc020>
TYPING blabla HERE
wr TYPING blabla HERE

at end
before curses TYPING blabla HERE
#
# AT THIS POINT:
# in this case, curses window is shown, with the text 'TYPING blabla HERE'
# ################


## CASE 2: THROUGH PIPE
##
## NOTE I get the same output, even if I try syntax as in SO1057638, like:
## python -c "print 'TYPING blabla HERE'" | python testcurses.py -
##
$ echo "TYPING blabla HERE" | ./testcurses.py -
['-'] 1
stdout/stdin (obj): <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0xb774a078> <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb774a020>
stdout/stdin (fn): 1 0
env(TERM): xterm xterm
stdin_termios_attr <class 'termios.error'>::(22, 'Invalid argument')
stdout_termios_attr [27906, 5, 1215, 35387, 15, 15, ['\x03', '\x1c', '\x7f', '\x15', '\x04', '\x00', '\x01', '\xff', '\x11', '\x13', '\x1a', '\xff', '\x12', '\x0f', '\x17', '\x16', '\xff', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']]
opening -
obj <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb774a020>
wr TYPING blabla HERE

at end
before curses TYPING blabla HERE
#
# AT THIS POINT:
# script simply exits, nothing is shown 
# ################
```

As far as I can see, the issue is: - whenever we pipe strings into the Python script, the Python script loses the reference to the *terminal* as `stdin`, and notices that the replaced `stdin` is not a `termios` structure anymore - and since `stdin` is no longer a terminal, `curses.initscr()` exits immediately without rendering anything.

So, my **question** is - in brief: can I somehow achieve, that the syntax `echo "blabla" | ./testcurses.py -` ends up showing the piped string in `curses`? More specifically: is it possible to retrieve a reference to the calling terminal's `stdin` from a Python script, even if this script is being "piped" to?

Thanks in advance for any pointers,

Cheers!

PS: the `testcurses.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python
# http://diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/stdin_stdout_stderr.html
# http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/42283-curses-disable-readline-replace-stdin
#
# NOTE: press 'q' to exit curses - Ctrl-C will screw up yer terminal

# ./testcurses.py "blabla"                  # works fine (curseswin shows)
# ./testcurses.py -                     # works fine, (type, enter, curseswins shows):
# echo "blabla" | ./testcurses.py "sdsd"        # fails to raise curses window 
# 
# NOTE: when without pipe: termios.tcgetattr(sys.__stdin__.fileno()): [27906, 5, 1215, 35387, 15, 15, ['\x03', 
# NOTE: when with pipe |   : termios.tcgetattr(sys.__stdin__.fileno()): termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument') 

import curses
import sys
import os
import atexit
import termios

def openAnything(source):            
    """URI, filename, or string --> stream

    http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/index.html#kgp.divein

    This function lets you define parsers that take any input source
    (URL, pathname to local or network file, or actual data as a string)
    and deal with it in a uniform manner.  Returned object is guaranteed
    to have all the basic stdio read methods (read, readline, readlines).
    Just .close() the object when you're done with it.
    """
    if hasattr(source, "read"):
        return source

    if source == '-':
        import sys
        return sys.stdin

    # try to open with urllib (if source is http, ftp, or file URL)
    import urllib                         
    try:                                  
        return urllib.urlopen(source)     
    except (IOError, OSError):            
        pass                              

    # try to open with native open function (if source is pathname)
    try:                                  
        return open(source)               
    except (IOError, OSError):            
        pass                              

    # treat source as string
    import StringIO                       
    return StringIO.StringIO(str(source)) 



def main(argv):

    print argv, len(argv)
    print "stdout/stdin (obj):", sys.__stdout__, sys.__stdin__ 
    print "stdout/stdin (fn):", sys.__stdout__.fileno(), sys.__stdin__.fileno()
    print "env(TERM):", os.environ.get('TERM'), os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown")

    stdin_term_attr = 0
    stdout_term_attr = 0
    try:
        stdin_term_attr = termios.tcgetattr(sys.__stdin__.fileno())
    except:
        stdin_term_attr = "%s::%s" % (sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1]) 
    try:
        stdout_term_attr = termios.tcgetattr(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
    except:
        stdout_term_attr = `sys.exc_info()[0]` + "::" + `sys.exc_info()[1]` 
    print "stdin_termios_attr", stdin_term_attr
    print "stdout_termios_attr", stdout_term_attr


    fname = ""
    if len(argv):
        fname = argv[0]

    writetxt = "Python curses in action!"
    if fname != "":
        print "opening", fname
        fobj = openAnything(fname)
        print "obj", fobj
        writetxt = fobj.readline(100) # max 100 chars read
        print "wr", writetxt
        fobj.close()
        print "at end"

    sys.stderr.write("before ")
    print "curses", writetxt
    try:
        myscreen = curses.initscr()
        #~ atexit.register(curses.endwin)
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

    sys.stderr.write("after initscr") # this won't show, even if curseswin runs fine

    myscreen.border(0)
    myscreen.addstr(12, 25, writetxt)
    myscreen.refresh()
    myscreen.getch()

    #~ curses.endwin()
    atexit.register(curses.endwin)

    sys.stderr.write("after end") # this won't show, even if curseswin runs fine


# run the main function - with arguments passed to script:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.stderr.write("after main1") # these won't show either, 
sys.stderr.write("after main2")     #  (.. even if curseswin runs fine ..)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done without getting the parent process involved. Fortunately, there's a way to get [bash](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/index.html) involved using [I/O redirection](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/io-redirection.html) :

```
$ (echo "foo" | ./pipe.py) 3<&0
```

That will pipe `foo` to `pipe.py` in a subshell with `stdin` duplicated into file descriptor 3. Now all we need to do is use that extra help from our parent process in the python script (since we'll inherit fd 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import curses

output = sys.stdin.readline(100)

# We're finished with stdin. Duplicate inherited fd 3,
# which contains a duplicate of the parent process' stdin,
# into our stdin, at the OS level (assigning os.fdopen(3)
# to sys.stdin or sys.__stdin__ does not work).
os.dup2(3, 0)

# Now curses can initialize.
screen = curses.initscr()
screen.border(0)
screen.addstr(12, 25, output)
screen.refresh()
screen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Finally, you can work around the ugly syntax on the command line by running the subshell first:

```
$ exec 3<&0  # spawn subshell
$ echo "foo" | ./pipe.py  # works
$ echo "bar" | ./pipe.py  # still works
```

That solves your problem, if you have `bash`.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the concise - and working - answer! :) I indeed use `bash`, as I'm on Ubuntu Lucid. My example, updated with your changes, can be found as [testcurses-stdin.py](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/testcurses-stdin.py?revision=75&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=75); and it should be called with '`(echo "blabla" | ./testcurses-stdin.py -) 3<&0`' ...

Comment: _PS: I must admit I have looked at [I/O redirection](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/io-redirection.html) hundreds of times - also before I posted this - and it always ends up confusing me; I would have really had a hard time figuring out the proper solution. Also, as I'm very fond of one-liners, the "`ugly syntax on the command line`" is actually **most** appreciated - one of the things I don't like is running ''`exec 3<&0`' before running something which is, essentially, a one liner_. Thanks again for the reply, Frédéric - and cheers!

Comment: Hi, thats quite an old question but the answer is very helpfull for half my problem. I now know how to pipe into my python curses application. I know it works to redirect the output to seen here https://github.com/liaonau/chooser/blob/master/chooser.c but I dont know how to do so in python. is there a way similar to dup2 to redirect the output of curses to /dev/tty to run the application in curses mode but pip a different output to the next application?

Comment: ok I figured somthing out which I could live with. I'm still curious on a solution I bet mine is quite hacky

Answer (score 13):

> The problem is that whenever I try the actual piping, that seems to mess up stdin, and the curses window never shows. 
>
> [...snip...]
>
>
> As far as I can see, the issue is: - whenever we pipe strings into the Python script, the Python script loses the reference to the terminal as stdin, and notices that the replaced stdin is not a termios structure anymore - and since stdin is no longer a terminal, curses.initscr() exits immediately without rendering anything.

Actually, the curses window does show, but since there is no more input on your brave new *stdin*, `myscreen.getch()` returns immediately. So it has nothing to do with curses testing whether *stdin* is a terminal.

So if you want to use `myscreen.getch()` and other curses input functions, you'll have to reopen your terminal. On Linux and *nix systems there is usually a device called `/dev/tty` that refers to the current terminal. So you can do something like:

```
f=open("/dev/tty")
os.dup2(f.fileno(), 0)
```

before your call to `myscreen.getch()`.

Comment: Thanks, ninjalj, for the nice explanation - it helps me a lot with understanding better how piping and standard I/O work! Btw, I'm not really interested in using '`myscreen.getch()`' - what I wanted to do, is pipe raw 'unformatted' data into this script, and have the script parse the data, and format it on screen using `ncurses` as in, "real-time" (_which is a whole set of different problems - but understanding the need for duplication of `stdin` was a real show stopper_). Cheers!

Comment: The funny thing is that if you're going to have the script running indefinitely and not use `myscreen.getch()`, the script you posted already works, it just exits way too fast to notice it.

Comment: PS: Just wanted to say that I updated [testcurses-stdin.py](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/testcurses-stdin.py?revision=76&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=75) so it duplicates `/dev/tty` instead of `fd3` - and now the script can be called plainly with '`echo "blabla" | ./testcurses-stdin.py -`'. Thanks again, ninjalj - and cheers!

Comment: PSS: Thanks also for the `getch` comment - I hoped that I could debug myself into a similar understanding - but I couldn't get neither `gdb` nor `pdb` nor `strace` to perform when running with pipes :) So the insight on `getch` is most valuable (_as I, basically, didn't even notice it was there :) - but it would still be needed to detect a key press for exit, I guess?_)! Cheers!

Comment: `strace` works perfectly fine with pipes for me: `echo "hell of world" | strace  -f python testpipe.py -`

Comment: Well, would I never... Of course, doing the `strace` after the pipe works fine! :) Thanks again, ninjalj - and cheers!