# The difference between bash and python pipes

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, pipe, python-3.2

I have the following three python scripts:

parent1.py

```
import subprocess, os, sys

relpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.abspath(relpath)
child = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(path, 'child.lisp')], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
sys.stdin = child.stdout
inp = sys.stdin.read()
print(inp.decode())
```

parent2.py:

```
import sys
inp = sys.stdin
print(inp)
```

child.py:

```
print("This text was created in child.py")
```

If i call parent1.py with:

```
python3 parent1.py
```

it gives me like expected the following output:

```
This text was created with child.py
```

if i call parent2.py with:

```
python3 child.py | python3 parent2.py
```

i get the same output. But in the first example i get the output of child.py as bytes and in the second i get it directly as a string. Why is this? Is it just a difference between python and bash pipes or is there something i could do otherwise to avoid this?

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999114/linux-pipe-into-python-ncurses-script-stdin-and-termios?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When python opens `stdin` and `stdout`, it detects what encoding to use and uses [text I/O](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) to give you unicode strings.

But `subprocess` does not (and can not) detect the encoding of the subprocess you start, so it'll return bytes. You can use a [`io.TextIOWrapper()` instance](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to wrap the `child.stdout` pipe to provide unicode data:

```
sys.stdin = io.TextIOWrapper(child.stdout, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Yep.  I'd like to add that there is just one kind of pipes in the OS and that's used by bash and Python just the same.  The interpretation of a stream can be different, and Python distinguishes the two cases; in one it interprets the input as bytes, in the other as string/unicode.

Comment: Thanks that worked. If i now want to do something like 'cat /bin/bash | parent2.py' it raises an UnicodeDecodeError because sys.stdin.read() doesn't return bytes. Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: @Alfe: Well, it still _interprets_ the input as bytes in both cases, it just automatically wraps the stream in a `TextIOWrapper` for you in the latter case. You can get at the underlying byte stream, or manually attach your own wrapper, in either case. But still, a useful point.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu: `sys.stdin` is just a regular `TextIOWrapper` like anything else. (Try printing its `repr`.) So, you can get at the bytes inside it in all the usual ways. For example, you can get its `fileno()` and `os.read()` from that (but don't mix up reads from both the wrapper and the fileno!).

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu: you could try to see if the object has an `encoding` attribute; if not, you need to wrap it; `if not hasattr(fileobj, 'encoding'): fileobj = io.TextIOWrapper(fileobj, encoding=...)`.