# Reclaim a redirected STDOUT temporarly in python

Tags: python, stdout, python-curses

I wrote a program, that shows a terminal UI with python curses. The program shall be able to read from STDIN and write the result **after the user interaction** to STDOUT w/o so the output may be redirected to another program or file like so:
`cat in.csv | my_tool > out.csv`

I figured out a working solution for STDIN to not interfere with curses ([Linux: Pipe into Python (ncurses) script, stdin and termios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999114/linux-pipe-into-python-ncurses-script-stdin-and-termios/4000997#4000997)).

I also found several solutions to redirect STDOUT temporarily to a file ([Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python))

If I read [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can-a-process-redirect-stdout-and-still-use-ncurses-in-a-terminal-4175411385/) right, it is possible in C. But the [newterm function](https://bugs.python.org/issue45934) is not exposed in the python wrapper?

Comment: Could it be an option to just write to STDERR?

Comment: I am looking for a solution, that is transparent to the user. So w/o the need to redirect streams when using the program as described above.

Comment: Writing to stdout what is expected to be redirected and to stderr what is not, is just what I learned in the early 80's, and what I still use...

Comment: I think you are conflating the terminal with stdout.  If the user redirects stdout to a file, then stdout *is* the file.  If you want to write to the controlling terminal, you cannot do so by manipulating stdout.  You need to write to the controlling terminal.